# Check if any of the files within a folder contain a pattern then return filename

Tags: bash

I'm writing a script that aim to automate the fulfill of some variables and I'm looking for help to achieve this:

I have a nginx sites-enabled folder which contain some reverses proxied sites.
I need to:

1. check if a pattern $var1 is found in any of the files in "/volume1/nginx/sites-enabled/"
2. return the name of the file containing $var1 as $var2

Many thanks for your attention and help!

I have found some lines but none try any files in a folder

```
if grep -q $var1 "/volume1/nginx/sites-enabled/testfile"; then
  echo "found"
fi
```

Comment: Have you looked at `man grep` and the `-l, --files-with-matches` option? E.g., `grep -l "$var1" "/volume1/nginx/sites-enabled/"*`?

Comment: This works great but return the full path to file not only the name of the file.
Can this be achieved?

Comment: Yes, you can either pipe to `basename` or loop and use a *parameter expansion*, e.g. `for i in $(grep -l -null "$var1" "/volume1/nginx/sites-enabled/"*); do echo "${i##*/}"; done`, or use `find` with the `-printf "%f"` conversion specifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` and `grep` can be used to produce a list of matching files:

```
find /volume1/nginx/sites-enabled/ -type f -exec grep -le "${var1}" {} +
```

The ‘trick’ is using `find`’s `-exec` and `grep`’s `-l`.

If you only want the filenames you could use:

```
find /volume1/nginx/sites-enabled/ -type f -exec grep -qe "${var1}" {} \; -exec basename {} \;
```

If you want to assign the result to a variable use command substitution (`$()`):

```
var2="$(find …)"
```

<sub>Don’t forget to quote your variables!</sub>

Comment: This does not seems to work:  `code`var2="$(find /volume1/nginx/sites-enabled/ -type f -exec grep -le "${var1}" {} +)"`code`

Comment: thanks for your answer: i have the fullpath in return, and i'm searching to obtain only the filename of the file containing $var1 :-)

Comment: if i do 
`var2="$(find /volume1/nginx/sites-enabled/ -type f -exec grep -le "${var1}" {} +)"`

i get '/volume1/nginx/sites-enabled/filname' as varriable for $var2

and im trying to get only `filename`

Comment: Ups!

Many thanks! This works!
`var2="$(find /volume1/nginx/sites-enabled/ -type f -exec grep -qe "${var1}" {} \; -exec basename {} \;)"`

Answer (score 0):

This command is the most traditional and efficient one which works on any Unix
without the requirement to have GNU versions of grep with special features.

The efficiency is, that xargs feeds the grep command as many filenames as arguments as it is possible according to the limits of the system (how long a shell command may be) and it excecutes the grep command by this only as least as possible.

With the -l option of grep it shows you only the filename once on a successful pattern search.

```
find /path -type f -print | xargs grep -l pattern
```

Comment: `find | xargs` _might_ fail on funny filenames. Why not `find -exec`?!

Comment: As you say "might" but in fact this works perfect and is the de facto solution on Unices. To your question: because then you execute the grep command as many times as you find a file, this puts more stress on the system (fork/exec). Experienced admins don't use -exec if any possible.

Comment: That’s what the `+` is for. It should execute `grep` more or less the same number of times as `xargs` would.

Comment: Hi Biffen, then the plus is a newer feature. I always try to use a syntax which is available on any flavour of Unix not only Linux / GNU related systems. And since I am doing this now since Microsoft Xenix and worked with very different Unices, I tend to stick to the more generic solutions which should work everywhere. Compatibility problems are really not fun. Example: last time I had a little PITA when using scripts written on Linux on a BSD system. This reminded me again to best program in a "defensive way" which is better for portability.

Comment: It’s part of POSIX (since _at least_ POSIX.1-2008), which is good enough for me. 

Comment: Yes you are right, then this is fine and I do not object, many thanks for your kind remark :-)

Comment: Thanks for your time and answers!
i'm gettint the fullpath with this command line aswell:

`var2="$(find /volume1/nginx/sites-enabled/ -type f -print | xargs grep -l $var1)"`

Comment: Best with `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...` to ensure you are working with nul-terminated strings.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have GNU Grep, this will store all files containing the contents of `$var1` in an [*array*](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) `$var2`.

```
for file in /volume1/nginx/sites-enabled/*
do
    if grep --fixed-strings --quiet "$var1" "$file"
    then
        var2+=("$file")
    fi
done
```

This will loop through NUL-separated paths:

```
while IFS= read -d'' -r -u9 path
do
    …something with "$path"
done 9< <(grep --fixed-strings --files-without-match --recursive "$var1" /volume1/nginx/sites-enabled)
```